# Поиск правильного MSBuild

Tags: bat, msbuild

На сколько я знаю, Visual Studio для сборки проектов использует MSBuild.

Как она находит нужный ей MSBuild? Ведь их может быть несколько.

В переменных окружения путь к нему я не нашёл. А мне нужно вызвать его из Bat-файла.